# Show that $x$ is commutative and $+$ is associative for these binary operations on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: binary-operations

\begin{align*}    
+ : \mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\\
((a,b),(c,d))&\mapsto(ad+bc,bd)\\[1cm]
\times: \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2 &\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2\\
((a,b),(c,d))&\mapsto(ac,bd)
\end{align*}
Questions:

a) Show that $\times$ is commutative.

b) Show that $+$ is associative.

c) Show that $\times$ is not distributive over $+$.

d) Show that there is a neutral element for $+$.

Comment: Please post your current working so that people can give you some useful help.

Comment: I have no current work, I have no idea where to start. :(

Comment: The problem with questions such as this is that they are messy to type up and show and they garner no rep points usually.

Comment: @Karl, do you know what "commutative" means?

Comment: What is your definition of a neutral element for +? Do you mean a 0?

Comment: @David Yes. (uxv = vxu). I understand these principles I'm just not sure how to go about answering the question with what I have. I haven't seen an example of these types of answers.

Comment: So what is a specific expression for $u\times v$ in this question?

Comment: @Vladhagen Yes, a 0.

Comment: @David (a,b)x(c,d)=(c,d)x(a,b)? If this isn't the answer I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: That's the first step.  Now using the definition of $\times$ given in the question you have to write down *exactly* (with no simplification) what is meant by the ${\rm LHS}$ and ${\rm RHS}$.  If you can do this then I think you will find it easy to explain why ${\rm LHS}={\rm RHS}$.

Answer (score 0):

**a**. Assuming that we commute in $\mathbb{R}$, $(a,b) \times (c,d) = (ac,bd) = (ca,db) = (c,d)\times(a,b)$

**b**. $$((a,b) + (c,d)) + (e,f) $$$$= (ad+bc,bd) + (e,f) $$$$= ((ad+bc)f+bde, bdf)$$
and we also have
       $$(a,b) + ((c,d) + (e,f)) $$$$= (a,b) + (cf+de,df) $$ $$= (adf + b(cf+de), bdf)$$ $$=((ad+bc)f+bde, bdf)$$

So we have associativity.

**c.** Here is a good counter example. We are going to go step by step on this first one now: $(1,2) \times ((3,4) + (1,1)) =(1,2) \times(3\cdot 1+4\cdot 1, 4 \cdot 1) =(1,2) \times (7,4) = (1\cdot 7, 2\cdot 4)$ $$ = (7,8)$$
$(1,2) \times (3,4) +(1,2) \times (1,1) = (3,8) + (1,2) $ $$= (14, 16)$$

So we have shown that distributive law does not work.

**d.** (0,1) is neutral. Notice that $(a,b) + (0,1) = (a\cdot1+ b\cdot 0 , b\cdot 1) = (a,b)$ for any $(a,b)$

Comment: End of answer b should be associativity not communtivity, no?

Comment: How come in the third line of answer b the term after (ad+bc)f there isn't an (ad+bc)e as well since there's a bde and a bdf?

Comment: If you examine the formula you gave for + carefully, we do **first entry** of first pair time **last entry** of last pair, then add that to **second entry** of first pair times **first entry** of second pair. That should give us what we have above.

Comment: When I do the calculations in answer c I'm getting (4,10) for both equations. How did you carry out the operations?

Comment: Notice that the plus rule you gave is not just direct addition. In my comment above I detail how the addition is to be done. You are just adding the two points directly, which is not the rule you gave for addition in your question. Again, you cannot just directly add the points. Follow your rules exactly.